# Java lwjgl applet noclassdeffound

Tags: java, applet, lwjgl, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to use my java applet on a html document but It just keeps giving the same errors over and over again.
I'm using eclipse. When i debug/run the applet it all works fine, but when I export it to a jar file and try to use it with a html document it gives this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/newdawn/slick/opengl/Texture
```

Here is my java code:
http://pastebin.com/B3R6nj1a

This is what the .jar file contains:

```
-lib
  -jars
    lwjgl.jar
    lwjgl_util.jar
    slick-util.jar
  -natives-win
    *all the dlls*

-META-INF
  -*files*

-res
  grass.png
  wood.png

.classpath
.project
Camera.class
Main$1.class
Main$2.class
Main.class
```

I do have everything right in the build path from my project. 
(So added the three external jars. And added native-win to lwjgl.jar)

This is my html code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <applet archive='3dtest.jar' Code='Main' width = "640" height = "480"></applet>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried to change "Code='Main' " to "Code='Main.class'" also didn't work.

Does anybody has any idea why I'm getting the error?
Thanks in advance.

***-Tim***

EDIT:
.classpath file:
    http://pastebin.com/i7y4XYaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is what the .jar file contains:
>
> ```
> -lib
>   -jars
>     lwjgl.jar
>     ...
> ```

Those Jars should not be there.  They should be separate Jars on the site referenced something like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<applet 
  archive='3dtest.jar,lwjgl.jar,lwjgl_util.jar,slick-util.jar,all_dlls.jar..' 
  code='Main' 
  width="640" 
  height="480">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

That is presuming the HTML is in the same directory as all the Jars.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this leads me to a blank applet that seems to be frozen

Comment: 1) Are all the Jar files digitally signed?  2) Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again. 3) Show the new source and structure in an edit to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the information everyone! I digitally signed it and fixed some External jars being in the wrong place. Thanks again!

Comment: Andrew Thompson sorry I forgot to do that, thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 0):

You need to post relevant code, not everything and hope someone will pick through it all.

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/newdawn/slick/opengl/Texture` means that class is not present in your classpath.

Comment: Yes but it does exist in the .classpath file I will edit the OP with the .classpath file.

Comment: then your program isn't packaged properly.

Comment: And how should I package it properly?

Comment: Have you actually tried googling it yet? People aren't too keen on regurgitating stuff that's WIDELY documented and covered in god knows how many tutorials...

Comment: Yes, I did google but I just endup with the same error or a blank applet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your applet is packaged properly when deploying it. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html